# Reduced row echelon matrix equivalence

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve whether two *m*-by-*n* matrices **A** and **B** are equivalent via

```
[a,ja] = rref(A,tol)
[b,jb] = rref(B,tol)
```

and then comparing

```
isequal(a,b) & isequal(ja,jb)
```

First, I don't really understand what `ja` and `jb` are. My problem is that the reduced row echelon form is very simple for both **A** and **B** and identical in all cases. I don't know whether this is on purpose or not. For example, I get equivalence for just

```
A = rand(40,3)
B = rand(40,3)
```

which I'm not sure is nonsense or not.

Comment: If you want to know what variables are supposed to be,  you can try `help rref` or `doc` rref. If you don't need them, you are not required to demand them as output arguments as the documentation shows. (In this case I believe you don't need them so you can just use `a` and `b`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to check if the [reduced row echelon forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of two matrices are element-wise equivalent. From how you've defined `A` and `B`, they are (it's effectively an overdetermined system, I believe). However, I think that you may have flipped your rows and columns. If instead you create `A` and `B` such that there are more columns than rows (i.e., an [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) of an underdetermined system):

```
A = rand(3,40)
B = rand(3,40)
```

then when you run `rref`, you'll see a much different output and your comparison will return false as you perhaps expected.

Also, I think that it is sufficient to use the following, as two matrices that are equal element-wise will surely share the same rank (or approximation thereof):

```
a = rref(A,tol);
b = rref(B,tol);
isequal(a,b)
```